# "Brusque" vs. "curt"

Tags: differences, adjectives

What is the diffence between *brusque* and *curt*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Curt* usually refers specifically to speech, while *brusque* is more general, referring to manner and behavior as well as speech. Also, a "*curt* reply" is a bit more rude than a *brusque* one.

Comment: It's a very small difference, but I think a curt reply is intentionally rude, while with a brusque reply, the rudeness is incidental. Thus, it's easier to invent a Polyanna-type excuse for the brusque response than the curt one.

Answer (score 2):

*Curt* can be emotionally neutral. *Brusque* displays some animosity.

The definitions are pretty close though.

Comment: +1 I agree with this answer. The words are synonyms in many situations. Brusque may (but does not always) imply some emotion.

Comment: I dunno. I think *brusque* implies a certain selfish disregard for the proprieties, i.e. it's oriented inwards. *Curt*, on the other hand, is more outward-oriented. I *wouldn't* assign more animosity to "brusque" than to "curt"; if anything, I'd put it the other way around. -- I think the moral of the story is, context is everything.

Answer (score 2):

*Curt*, not *brusque*, suggests possible animosity. Brusque people are in a hurry, often to attend to business. Curt people brook no dissent.

Comment: Thank you for showing me a new meaning of the word "brook". 